# Java Android: How is it possible that a method returns an instance of an abstract class?

Tags: java, object, abstract-class

The method **open()** of the **AssetManager** class returns an object of type **InputStream** but **InputStream** is an abstract class so it should not be possible  to have an object of this type (an object of the type of an abstract class). How it really works?

Comment: It returns a concrete implementation of the abstract class? It's how OOP works. Same way you can pass instances of InputStream to methods?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for your reply but I didn't understand it. How can I return from a method an object of the type of an abstract class?

Comment: It doesn't really return an instance of the abstract class; it returns an instance of a concrete subclass of that abstract class, which can be stored in a variable whose type is the abstract class.

Comment: @FredK Thanks for reply. So, if I get it straight, inside the open() method implementation there is a piece of code where a subclass of InputStream is created and an instance of this subclass is returned?

Comment: You can't, you return an implementation of the abstract class. Same way you can't return an instance of an interface, you return something that implements the interface. This is one of the foundations of OOP: a subclass is-a parent class.